# Regex to only match substring A when substring B was not found

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

This seems to have been asked a lot of times before, but I could not find any answer that solves my concrete request.

Having input strings like:

```
1. The road is closed.
2. Closed road ahead.
3. There is a closed lane.
4. The lane is closed.
```

What regular expression matches the word `closed` ONLY IF the word `lane` is not part of the input string? This should be as general as possible in terms of

- that the word `lane` can exist before or after the word `closed`,
- that any number and type of words can stand between `lane` and `closed`, not only `a` or `is` as used in the examples above.

What I would expect is matching `closed` in input strings 1 and 2, but not in 3 and 4 (because either of them contains the forbidden word `lane`).

I tried to do this with negative lookaheads and lookbehinds but this still matches the occurence of `closed` in all four input strings.

```
(?<!lane)(?!lane)(closed)
```

Regex flavor is Python 3.4.

Comment: To test your reghex try http://pythex.org/ or http://www.pythonregex.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^(?!.*\blane\b)(?=.*\bclosed\b).*$
```

Try this .See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/49

Comment: That's a nice solution.

Comment: Cool! Do you also know how to make it only match the word `closed` instead of the whole string?

Comment: @Dirk only closed? you want to extract it?

Comment: Uhm no, matching the complete line seems sufficient for my task. Thanks!